# Using chain rule in reverse

Tags: calculus

I'm new to calculus and so i'm trying to get the integral of this function:

> $$\int(1+4x^2)^{\frac12}\ dx$$

I would appreciate it if someone can give me a simple way to solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: Think about removing the square root. Think about trigonometric substitution.

Comment: @MrJava99 Where does this integral come from? Have you learnt substitution or integration by parts?

Comment: The chain rule in reverse would be integration by substitution, but this function is not amenable to that approach. New title needed....?

Comment: @TobyMak I'm using the arc length formula on the function f(x) = x^2

Comment: @PJK That's the problem, i'm not quite good at using them so i thought about finding an easier approach but it seems that it's the only way. I guess i have to spent some more time learning them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get rid of $$ \sqrt {1+4x^2}$$ by transforming it into something like $$ \sqrt {1+\tan ^2 t} =\sec  t$$

Hyperbolic substitutions also work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with trigonometic substitutions but i think i have to learn how to use them.

Comment: Trig substitutions are part of Calculus II course. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any recommendations to start with?

Comment: Check a calculus book. It is not hard to learn.